# Sample from distribution given by histogram

Tags: r, sampling, density-function, histogram

Given a histogram obtained using given data points, how do I randomly sample from the distribution predicted by the histogram?

Any conceptual comment / R code would be welcome.

Comment: Your title seems to be asking how to sample from a histogram-as-population-pdf while the body text seems to be asking how to sample from a kernel-density-estimate-as-population-pdf  (two different problems, the second of which is solved [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43674/simple-sampling-method-for-a-kernel-density-estimator) and [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82797/how-to-draw-random-samples-from-a-non-parametric-estimated-distribution)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the sampling from a kernel density estimate is solved [once](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43674/simple-sampling-method-for-a-kernel-density-estimator) or [twice](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82797/how-to-draw-random-samples-from-a-non-parametric-estimated-distribution) already, I'll focus on sampling from a histogram-as-population-pdf.

The idea is simply

```
For each observation in the new sample

  1. choose a histogram bin according to the proportions of 
     the original sample (treated as a discrete pmf)

  2. sample uniformly from that bin-interval
```

For example in R:

```
#create an original histogram
x=rgamma(200,4)
xhist=hist(x,freq=FALSE)

#sample from it
samplesize=400
bins=with(xhist,sample(length(mids),samplesize,p=density,replace=TRUE)) # choose a bin
result=runif(length(bins),xhist$breaks[bins],xhist$breaks[bins+1]) # sample a uniform in it
hist(result,freq=FALSE,add=TRUE,bord=3)
```

---

Just for completeness, (since sampling from the kernel density estimate* is very simple):

```
repeat nsim times:
  sample (with replacement) a random observation from the data
  sample from the kernel, and add the previously sampled random observation
```

* note that some kernels - like fourth order kernels - are not densities and this assumes that the kernel is a density

In R, for a Gaussian kernel and bandwidth h, with data in x:

```
 dnorm(nsim,m=sample(x,nsim,replace=TRUE), s=h)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
y <- density(x)
x.new <- rnorm(length(x), sample(x, size = length(x), replace = TRUE), y$bw)
plot(y)
lines(density(x.new), col = "blue")
```

Note that the density function uses kernel = "gaussian" as default. So to generate gaussian random numbers from a particular density you just need to use rnorm with the mean values equal to the original series and the standard deviation equal to the smoothing bandwidth. In this example I am resampling those mean values to generate different simulations. You can see this example in the density function documentation [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/density.html).

Comment: Can you provide some text to explicate this code?

Comment: Sorry, I've added some clarification. Note that this example is taken from the density function documentation.

Comment: As far as I can see you're producing a sample from a particular Gaussian. That's not in general the distribution predicted by any histogram (or kernel density estimate). There seems to be confusion here between the kernel and the data.

Comment: I had the same feeling when I read the documentation of the density package, but they seem to justify it by saying that a kernel density fit is an equally-weighted mixture.

Comment: I don't use R except very occasionally, so I am guessing what the code.  But the bandwidth of a kernel will usually be much less than the SD of the data. Either way, the assumption that the data are Gaussian will in general be quite false.